# Issue with PostgreSQL installation

Tags: postgresql

I have started learning RoR, now i am trying to install PostgreSQL for performing backend operation with the database.

I have two machines where i installed Postgresql, it runs well in one machine. In another machine i uninstalled the PostgreSQL and re installed it. After re installing i could not able to start the PostgreSQL service.

Below is the error log that i see in PostgreSQL log file

```
2011-12-02 04:40:53 PST LOG:  incomplete startup packet
2011-12-02 04:40:53 PST LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2011-12-02 04:40:54 PST LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 0/15F44E0
2011-12-02 04:40:54 PST LOG:  record with zero length at 0/15F44E0
2011-12-02 04:40:54 PST LOG:  redo is not required
2011-12-02 04:40:54 PST LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2011-12-02 04:40:54 PST LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2011-12-02 04:40:54 PST LOG:  could not receive data from client: An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.
```

I have been trying several ways to solve this, but no use on all the steps. Could any one please give me a hand on this?

I am installing PostgreSQL Version 9.0.5 in Windows 7 machine (64 bit)

Comment: Small suggestion if you really want help with this; at least mention the OS we are talking about, which Postgres version you are trying to install, which installer you are using, etc. More, much more, details.

Comment: Sorry..! I am installing PostgreSQL Version 9.0.5 in Windows 7 machine (64 bit) Also updated in the question..

Comment: I directly downloaded the exe file and installed the application.. is this information enough.. or pls mention if you require more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I correct in saying that you once had a working installation of Postgres on the same machine? But you uninstalled it and are now trying to install it on the same machine again?

I was in a similar situation once but it had to do with the service account the installer creates. Did you create a new service account for postgres, or are you trying to re-use the old one? If so, are you sure you are using the right password for the account?

Another hunch I got; the port on which the new Postgres server is listening, is it really free? It appears to me that it cannot open the listening port specified in postgresql.conf.

Or, yet another hunch; if I read the log correct I get the feeling that you are re-using the old data directory. Is this true? And if so, what was the version of the previous Postgres installation?

Sorry I don't have answer, but I do have questions that might lead you to a solution.

Comment: Yes.. you are right. I installed PostgreSQL 9.1 at first, and then after uninstalling this i installed 9.0.5. When this issue continued, i found a suggestion in a site to delete the old file under /PostgreSQL/data and /PostgreSQL/bid directories. I tried this too, but no use..

Also the port i configured to install this is available for use.. i have checked it by using **netstat -a**

Comment: Did you delete everything under /data? Or did you leave something? Because the log states that it sees an unsafe shut down. Seeing as you cannot start the service to begin with, I think that the unsafe shut down is one from the 9.1 installation.

Comment: At first time i did not delete the folders and re-installed PostgreSQL.. i think this should be the reason why i cannot able to start the service.. any suggestion on fixing this?

Comment: My first try would be uninstalling the current Postgres server. Then reinstall but using a different, new, data directory. That way you are almost guaranteed to have a clean installation. It rules out any (or most) configuration errors you might come across.

Comment: Might be something in the Windows registry blocking correct usage then? Last thing you could try: uninstall Postgres and everything related. Search the registry for Postgres leftovers and delete those as well. Then retry installing in a new data directory. ONLY do this if you know what you are doing obviously! Be careful with the changes.